# Tag Synonym Request: [lense] -> [lenses]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think [this tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/lense/) was just created by [Pablo](https://askubuntu.com/users/6107/pablo) maybe as a mistake for the [lenses tag.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lenses)

So I'm not sure if it should just be deleted, or synomized with lenses (Wikipedia says "lense" is an appropriate but uncommon spelling of lens).

I also kind of think we should add a tag for "lens" and synomize it with these two.

I don't have permission to even request the synonym, but maybe someone else can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this got created.

(FYI, we like to have answers on questions so they don't look unanswered, please.)